# System.Net.Http.HttpClient with AutomaticDecompression and GetAsync (timeout) vs GetStringAsync (working

Tags: android, xamarin, dotnet-httpclient

I have the following code to make requests to a REST API, using Xamarin and an Android device:

```
public class ApiBase
{
  HttpClient m_HttpClient;

  public ApiBase(string baseAddress, string username, string password)
  {
    if (!baseAddress.EndsWith("/"))
    {
      baseAddress += "/";
    }
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    if (handler.SupportsAutomaticDecompression)
    {
      handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
    }
    m_HttpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
    m_HttpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    var credentialsString = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
    m_HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentialsString);
    m_HttpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
  }

  protected async Task<XElement> HttpGetAsync(string method)
  {
    try
    {

      HttpResponseMessage response = await m_HttpClient.GetAsync(method);
      if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
        // the request was successful, parse the returned string as xml and return the XElement
        var xml = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<XElement>();
        return xml;
      }
      // the request was not successful -> return null
      else
      {
        return null;
      }
    }
    // some exception occured -> return null
    catch (Exception)
    {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

If i have it like this, the first and the second call to HttpGetAsync work perfectly, but from the 3rd on the `GetAsync`stalls and eventually throws an exception due to the timeout. I send these calls consecutively, there are not 2 of them running simultaneously since the results of the previous call are needed to decide the next call. 
I tried using the app Packet Capture to look at the requests and responses to find out if i'm sending an incorrect request. But it looks like the request which fails in the end is never even sent.

Through experimentation i found out that everything works fine if don't set the `AutomaticDecompression`.

It also works fine if i change the `HttpGetAsync` method to this:

```
protected async Task<XElement> HttpGetAsync(string method)
{
  try
  {
    // send the request
    var response = await m_HttpClient.GetStringAsync(method);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
    {
      return null;
    }
    var xml = XElement.Parse(response);
    return xml;
  }
  // some exception occured -> return null
  catch (Exception)
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

So basically using i'm `m_HttpClient.GetStringAsync` instead of `m_HttpClient.GetAsync` and then change the fluff around it to work with the different return type. If i do it like this, everything works without any problems.

Does anyone have an idea why `GetAsync` doesn't work properly (doesn't seem to send the 3rd request) with `AutomaticDecompression`, where as `GetStringAsync` works flawlessly?

Comment: There are few bugs with HTTP client and also it does not use Native handlers. I use Modern Http Client which faster.

Answer (score 1):

There are bug reports about this exact issue:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=21477

The bug is marked as RESOLVED FIXED and the recomended action is to update to the latest stable build. But there are other (newer) bugreports that indicate the same thing that are still open, ex:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=34747

I made a workaround by implementing my own HttpHandler like so:

```
        public class DecompressionHttpClientHandler : HttpClientHandler
        {
            protected override async Task SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                request.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
                var msg = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
                if (msg.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Contains("gzip"))
                {
                    var compressedStream = await msg.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                    var uncompresedStream = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(compressedStream, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress);
                    msg.Content = new StreamContent(uncompresedStream);
                }
                return msg;
            }
        }
```

Note that the code above is just an example and not a final solution. For example the request will not be compressed and all headers will be striped from the result. But you get the idea.